# Is there are term for location plus orientation, without magnitude?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there a concise, accepted term for a piece of information that describes location (translation from origin) plus orientation (angular position / attitude), but ignoring magnitude?

**In a little more detail**

My formal mathematical training ended with differential equations in engineering school some 10 years ago, so forgive me if I use the wrong terms here. From what I know, and the limited fruits of my Googling:

Given three fundamental geometrical aspects in n-dimensional space:

- Location
- Orientation
- Magnitude

I can find terms that describe:

- Location only: location, point, position, location vector, position vector
- Orientation only: orientation, attitude, angular position
- Magnitude only: magnitude, length
- Orientation + magnitude: vector, spatial vector, geometric vector

I cannot find terms that describe:

- **Location + orientation** (this is specifically what I'm looking for)
- Location + magnitude
- Location + magnitude + direction

**The context**

I'm writing a code library that's focused on describing and manipulating shapes in a two dimensional plane. Both in the code itself and in my natural language discussions of it, it would be very expedient to be able to name the location-plus-orientation of the entities. Just as in engineering it is so frequent that we need to discuss the orientation-and-magnitude of things (such as forces) that we use a single word for it: commonly just 'vector'. I'm on the verge of coming up with my own hacky portmanteau, but if there is an existing accepted term I would prefer to use that.

Comment: So you mean you have an object which is sitting somewhere in space and pointing in a specific direction? This can be described using two vectors, one is the position vector which can take values in the whole of the ambient space you're working in (probably $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$), and the other is the orientation vector which will be a unit vector (magnitude identical to $1$) which will take values in the sphere of the appropriate dimension.

Comment: @DanielRust Yes, exactly. I'm looking for a single term--ideally a single *word*--that describes the two together. I've added a brief paragraph to my question explaining why this matters.

Comment: Perhaps the word 'configuration' is suitable? It at least seems to me that you are describing points in a 'configuration space'. [relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space#Rigid_body)

Comment: @DanielRust That looks spot on. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this term can be used in a more general setting (it's very commonly used in robotics for instance to describe the space of all possible states or, for example, a robotic arm with articulated joints) I think the word *configuration* would be suitable for your purposes. The [wiki page on configuration spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space#Rigid_body) specifically mentions the case of the term being used when describing spaces of possible positions and orientations of rigid bodies in space. This can of course be generalised to higher/lower dimensions and also take into account other parameters if needed.

Comment: That's it. The discussion of rigid bodies in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is perfectly analogous to what I'm doing in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

In robotics or computer vision the term ***pose*** is generally used to describe the position and orientation of a rigid object.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pose_%28computer_vision%29) says:

> The combination of position and orientation is referred to as the pose
>   of an object. [...] The pose can be described by means of a rotation
>   and translation transformation which brings the object from a
>   reference pose to the observed pose.

You could also use the term [***rigid transformation***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation), to describe a transformation that contains a translation component and a rotation component, but no scale component. Although this usually refers more to the change in location than the location itself.